# As can be reversed in this example Xaxis

Tags: datetime, highcharts, reverse

The series are fine, but xaxis is reversed,but the code "reversed: true," it is necessary for the proper order of Yaxis

In summary, I need solely reversed Xaxis, for this example:

```
$(function() {
var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
    chart: {
        renderTo: 'container',
        type: 'line',
    },
        xAxis: {
    type: 'datetime',
    reversed: true,
    labels: {
        formatter: function() {
            return Highcharts.dateFormat('%m/%d/%y', this.value, true);
        }
    },
    showLastLabel: true
},
    series: [{
        data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4],

        pointInterval: 1 * 3600 * 1000,
        pointStart: (new Date()).getTime() - 1 * 24 * 3600 * 1000 

       }]
});
```

});

http://jsfiddle.net/raposu/K5tpe/4/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it finally.....    ***.reverse()***

```
   series: [{
        data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4].reverse(),

        pointInterval: 1 * 3600 * 1000,
        pointStart: (new Date()).getTime() - 1 * 24 * 3600 * 1000 

       }]
```

http://jsfiddle.net/K5tpe/7/

thanks

Answer (score 0):

You say you do not want it reversed but you have `reversed: true` set. But this is because you want the data in appropriate order. But you are assigning an arbitrary date via `(new Date()).getTime() - 1 * 24 * 3600 * 1000`. But this is in ascending order...but you are setting `reversed: true` so it is descending order...but you want it in ascending order.

So, remove `reversed: true` and you have data going in ascending chronological order (which is a good thing). Since you do not provide an example of an expected outcome this is the best answer I can come up with.

EDIT:

If you want your data to be in the ascending order starting from N hours ago you should first set it so that you send in the x/y values at the same time instead of doing point start. I find it is always better to send in time/value pairs. See this updated [example](http://jsfiddle.net/wergeld/K5tpe/5/).

Comment: One possible solution? .....

xaxis is always left to right direction 1,2,3,4, etc..

can be done without using `reversed: true` that initially xaxis 8,9,7,6,5,4 .... 1

pointEnd: (there is this syntax?) think not, but is there any alternative?

Comment: Finally you can solve the problem by reversing the output data with php,

thank you all for your help @wergeld

Answer (score 0):

Ok, but if you remove reversed, then reversed Yaxis too. I need the data as they are in the example.

Are inverted data 24 hours ago until now. If you have ***reversed: false,*** the time  data is correct but the data is invested, if I ***reversed: true,*** the data is correct but the time invested.

is tongue twister of hard to explain,

thanks

Comment: That makes no sense whatsoever. If you set reverse: false on the xAxis it does not reverse the yAxis data.